# Compilable and Runnable JOGL application not drawing triangle

Tags: java, awt, opengl-es-2.0, jogl, glsles

I'm trying to use JOGL in a Java AWT based application.

I'm new to OpenGL so I'm starting with a classic draw triangle example.

I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0.

Having looked at several tutorials online & spending many hours pouring over & over my code I'm at a loss as to why my otherwise compilable & runnable program ( i.e. no exceptions are being directly thrown ) does not draw anything other than the clear colour.

The vertex data, shader code, and gl setup procedure are all taken from tutorials.

the vertex shader code:

```
#version 100
attribute vec3 vPosition;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vPosition,1.0);
}
```

the fragment shader code:

```
#version 100
precision mediump float;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

the vertex data:

```
float[] vertexPositions =
{
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f
};

FloatBuffer lBuffer = CommonFuncs.getFloatBuffer( 1024 );
lBuffer.put( vertexPositions );
```

I set 'vPosition' like so:

on initialise:

```
theRenderer.glBindAttribLocation( theProgram, 0, "vPosition" );
```

on display:

```
theRenderer.glUseProgram( theProgram );
theRenderer.glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, lBuffer );
theRenderer.glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
theRenderer.glDrawArrays( GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );
theRenderer.glDisableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
theRenderer.glUseProgram( 0 );
```

however I see nothing on screen besides the cyan blue clear colour I specified & called previously in 'display'.

I've tried all sorts of different configurations, trying to specify a modelview & projection matrix, and multiply the vPosition by those. But the tutorials I'm looking at don't do anything with any matrices & still draw a triangle. I just don't get what I'm missing & hope a fresh pair of eyes with more experience can help.

Thanks.

Comment: post more code. Just a guess - maybe you're clearing display after the triangle has been drawn (glClear in OpenGL, not sure if JOGL uses the same call).

Comment: You probably need to reset the buffer position after you added your vertex data to it. Try `lBuffer.flip()` after the `lBuffer.put(...)`.

Comment: Maybe this simple example can help: https://github.com/sgothel/jogl/blob/master/src/test/com/jogamp/opengl/test/junit/jogl/demos/es2/RedSquareES2.java

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed an issue caused by not calling lBuffer.flip() - woe is me :S thank you @Reto Koradi for spotting my simple mistake - a fresh pair of eyes did the trick after all :)